# Is it possible to calculate position from accelerometer?

Tags: matlab, position, controls, accelerometer

Okay, so i here is my project:

I'm designing a RC hovercraft. When the hovercraft is not moving i wan't it to stabilize itself, using a accelerometer. It's important to note, that the acc, will always be flat, meaning that no other axis' then the z, should be influenced by gravity. Stabilize in this case means, that if you push the hovercraft, it should try to obtain the same position. I have made a matlab code, were i'm receiving accelerometer data, from the x-axis. I then created a moving averaging filter, to smooth thing out, and made a threshold, meaning that any values below a certain number would be considered zero. I then plit the graph, and it' looking okay. The problem, which you proberly already know, is that i have to track the position of the hovercraft, to know how far away from it's original position it has been pushed. When i plot the velocity, and make a statement that says if the last acceleration data has been zero, i can assume that the accelerometer is not moving, and the velocity is also set to zero. But when i plot the position, it's rly not good at all. It will quit often move the same direction in the plot, even though i'm moving the accelerometer in both directions.

I have considered using a kalman filter, but before i'm going any further, i wanna make sure, this is even possible to do.

I'm using the MPU-9150 for acceleration measurement.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the accelerometer+gyro+magnetometer you will not be able to calculate accurate position within the limit of reasonable needs, because the first integration will cause some not-accurate velocity, and second integration will cause error in position that will increase as time pass.

The physics is simple, the speed is not absolute, so you can't say if you are moving or not, so you cant correct the drift.